# django edit model form not working

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I was trying to make a edit model form by passing the model instance.. but it dose not update the data..

here's the code:

-----views.py-----

```
def edit_form(request,student_usn):
    student=Student.objects.get(usn=student_usn)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=StudentForm(request.POST,instance=student)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    else:
        form=StudentForm(instance=student)
    return render_to_response('edit_form.html',{"form":form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---------edit_form.html---------

```
<html>
    <title>Edit form</title>
    <head><h1>Edit Student</h1></head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_table}}
            <input type="submit" value="Update">            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

-----urls.py--

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^index/$', login,{'template_name': 'index.html'}),
    url(r'^profile/$',profile),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout),
    url(r'^profile/(.+)$',edit_form)


]
```

now, everything is working fine.. but data is not updated..!!

Comment: Can you add your `urls.py`?

Comment: yea.. done.. @pythad

Comment: you form action maps to thanks but I don't see url `thanks` in your urls.py

Comment: i put that afterwards when action="." wasn't working..

Answer (score 0):

Your form action goes to `/thanks/`, but your method is `edit_form`. You should change the action pointing to the url that `edit_form` goes.

Comment: yea..did that also. by making action="." but still it dosen't work.

Comment: Your action doesn't look right, because your edit form takes a parameter `student_usn`, but you passed nothing. You should pass the student's `usn` to the url.

Comment: Also your url definition is wrong, it should be `url(r'^profile/(?P<student_usn>\w+)$',edit_form)`. Please read more about django url definition: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: i do pass student_usn.. as i have this in other template  <a href="/profile/{{student.usn}}" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" style="width:50px; height:30px;" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=350,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0'); return false;">edit</a>  so. student_usn is passed correctly.. nd evn when the form is loaded.. the instance selected is correct.. but its not updating the data

Comment: Can you make sure that when you submit your form, `edit_form` is executed? Try to print something in the method to make sure that it's executed.

Comment: yea.. definitely edit_form is working.. otherwise template wouldn't have loaded itself.. also the student with that particular usn is also selected in the instance of the form.. only problem is data not being updated!!